# How to find which procedure generated a sp_send_dbmail request

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a user who is reporting that is receiving emails (from our system), that should not receive. The DBA who set up the instance and database in question is no longer working here and isn't available for questions.

I've perused the `sysmail_sentitems` table to confirm the messages were sent, but I would like to trace each mail item back to the procedure that executed `sp_send_dbmail`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't be surprised about downvotes. Be sure to read "[_How do I ask a good question?_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" text in Help Center. Your question may seem to broad and lacking of your effort, and thus the downvotes. It is normal, we have some strange guys here (for example the one, who downvote without giving any comment, why). Don't take it too personally! :>

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and edit trejder.

Comment: Nope problem. And, by the way, don't express your gratitude by writing "thanks"! :> These are also off-topic. Please, write no answers like that (will be closed) and limit comments like that to minimum (may be closed). If you want to thank for anything, then simply _upvote_ question, answer or comment. Upvote anything you find useful here. Like I just did with your question and comment above. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could search procedure definitions for `sp_send_dbmail` and go from there:

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO

SELECT 
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id) AS ProcedureName,
    [definition] AS ProcedureDefinition
FROM 
    sys.sql_modules
WHERE 
    objectproperty(object_id,'IsProcedure') = 1
    AND 
    [definition] LIKE '%sp_send_dbmail%'
```

This probably isn't a fantastic solution if you're sending e-mail from many procedures.

Comment: Thanks, I also added further restrictions in the where clause to `[definition]` column and narrowed it down to 2 possible procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in a position to test this out right now, but here's what I'd do:

1. Start an extended event session for the execution of sp_send_dbmail. Make sure to capture the call_stack.
2. Wait for the proc to be called
3. From the extended event output, correlate the call stack information with cached plans in the procedure cache. That should point you to where it's being called from.